# Data/logic structure for a dichotomous key (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, data-structures

For a school project, I'm making a webapp that presents a [dichotomous key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichotomous_key).

First, it shows a list of possible items. The user picks one in their head. The app then presents the user with a question and buttons for `Yes` or `No`. A new question is asked based on the response to the previous one. This continues until only one item fits the user's responses.

My question is how to store the data. My initial idea was a nested array. Here's an example using fruits:

```
Options: Apple, Orange, Banana, Pear

0 - "Is it shaped like a sphere?"           Initial question
1 -                                         Yes response
    0 - "Do you eat the peel/skin?"         Subsequent question
    1 - "Apple"                             Answer based on Yes response
    2 - "Orange"                            Answer based on No response
2 -                                         No response to initial
    0 - "Is it yellow                       Subsequent question
    1 - "Banana"                            Answer based on Yes response
    2 - "Pear"                              Answer based on No response
```

But, this way seems like it could get pretty unwieldy with a lot of data. Is there a better way to structure this?

This has to be completely JS/HTML; I don't want to use a database or anything like that.

Comment: As long as there aren't any "crossings", it's not going to get hugely cleaner--I mean, it's just a tree or digraph. I'd consider using objects as nodes, it might make things a bit easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using a table like this (technically, it can be an array of objects)

```
                                Apple Orange Banana Pear
Is it shaped like a sphere?     +     +      -      -
Do you eat the peel/skin?       +     -      -      +
Is it yellow?                   -     -      +      -
```

It is more flexible compared to nested objects or graphs because you can determine questions and their order dynamically, depending on what items are selected.

Comment: The table can store any combination of questions and answers, but it loses the tree-like structure of the dichotomous key in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

In JSON:

```
{
  "Question": "Is it shaped like a sphere?",
  "Yes":
    {
      "Question": "Do you eat the peel/skin?",
      "Yes": "Apple",
      "No": "Orange"
    },
  "No":
    {
      "Question": "Is it yellow?",
      "Yes": "Banana",
      "No": "Pear"
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this approach offer significant advantages over a standard array?

Comment: An array like yours probably provides the same functionality (there is always more than one way to do it). What I didn't like about it, were the "magic" numbers (0, 1, 2) which have no obvious meaning. The meaning of the numbers has to be represented in the code. Storing the question/answers as a plain Javascript object makes it easy to manipulate whole decision trees. (Well, somehow you could achieve that as well with Arrays; maybe it comes down to a matter of taste.)